# What is a good way to override/edit specific fields in a data frame?

Tags: r

Let's say for `mtcars`, the mpg for Toyota Corolla should be 23.9 instead of 33.9. How would you go about doing it?

For the purpose of this question, please assume that there can be multiple rows of Toyota Corolla.

Example 1:

```
mtcars["Toyota Corolla" & mtcars$mpg==33.9,] <- 23.9
```

gives

> Error in "Toyota Corolla" & mtcars$mpg == 33.9 : 
>     operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Example 2:

```
mtcars[mtcars$mpg==33.9,"mpg"] <- 23.9
```

is not safe because there may be multiple values of `mpg`.

Comment: For your ex2, another reason to not attempt that is [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), where floating-point comparisons are not assured (and not always intuitive).

Comment: Good point @r2evans! The alternative should be mtcars[near(mtcars$mpg, 33.9), "mpg"] <-23.9

Comment: So to combine Ronak's answer and this comment, then `mtcars[rownames(df) == "Toyota Corolla" & dplyr::near(mtcars$mpg, 33.9),"mpg"] <- 23.9`. If you don't want to load `dplyr` just for that, the function is rather simple (`abs(x-y)<.Machine$double.eps^0.5`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could check the `rownames` instead and update the value

```
df <- mtcars
df[rownames(df) == "Toyota Corolla", "mpg"] <- 23.9

#....
#Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla      23.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#....
```

---

Or if we want to be extra sure and check `mpg` variable as well, we can do

```
df[rownames(df) == "Toyota Corolla" & df$mpg == 33.9, "mpg"] <- 23.9
```